# Customizing emacs jabber notifications

Tags: emacs

I use jabber to connect to gmail talk and when I get a new message and I'm not in the jabber window I get notified in the modeline.

I unfortunately can not find a way to customize this message. The default is too obtrusive for me (ideally a simple asterisk in the modeline in an unobtrusive color would be enough).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet will give you a plain notification count in the mode line (e.g. `[42]`):

```
(eval-after-load "jabber-activity"    
  '(progn
     (setq global-mode-string (delete '(t jabber-activity-mode-string) global-mode-string))
     (add-to-list 'global-mode-string jabber-activity-count-in-title-format)))
```

Comment: I had to restart emacs and these lines gave me an error - the variables are unknown at startup (I use `(require 'jabber-autoloads)`). Do you know what else should I autoload? The solution is working if I evaluate it after I fire up jabber.

Comment: Hm, I edited the snippet to only run after `jabber-activity` has been loaded, but just realised that it needs to be run after jabber-activity-mode has been _activated_... There's probably a way to achieve that (apart from just making this a function you need to call with `M-x`), though it doesn't appear to me immediately...